# Memory leak using QVector

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

```
QVector<cLibraryRecord> Library;
...
Library.push_back(cLibraryRecord(ReaderFullName, BookGenre, BookTitle, AuthorsFullName, IssueDate, ReturnDate));
...
Library.remove(i);
```

QVector::remove() does not clear the memory. How can I clean the memory?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about `cLibraryRecord` ?

Comment: @Бориска Сосиска: yes it does. If there's a leak, its more likely to be in the `cLibraryRecord` class.

Comment: I think, `cLibraryRecord`'s destructor has problem. If you can, put the `cLibraryRecord` code.

Comment: What do you man by "clean the memory"? What do you expect the vector to do?

Comment: Source Code  http://zalil.ru/31758142

Comment: probably something I do not understand, but I do not allocate memory anywhere.

Comment: jalf, clean = deallocate

Comment: After entering the data into the program, the memory occupied by the process increases. After removing the data using Library.remove (i), the space occupied by the application in memory is not reduced.

Comment: That normal if you're looking at the task manager in windows or `top` or similar on most unix-like systems. Situations where your process image actually shrink are really rare. That is not a leak.

Comment: What evidence do you have that you even have a memory leak?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QVector.remove()` always calls the destructor for the contained object, but the reserved size (returned by `QVector::capacity()`) doesn't shrink automatically when you remove elements.

You can use `QVector::squeeze()` to release the unused reserved memory.

But you can also have a memory leak in your class `cLibraryRecord`.

See Qt documentation for more details: [Qt containers growth strategies](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/containers.html#growth-strategies).

Comment: probably something I do not understand, but I do not allocate memory anywhere. QVector::squeeze() does not help. My source сode zalil.ru/31758142